# How to draw curved cylinders c# open gl

Tags: c#, opengl

I need to draw curved cylinders in C#, WinForms and OpenGL.
Actually, I am drawing a picture of bender so I need to draw his arms and legs.

[image]

So how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is generating geometry for a circle transported along a spline.

Perhaps these'll help.

- http://www.gamedev.net/topic/373943-3d-bezier-curve---3d-pipe/

  - http://www.unchainedgeometry.com/jbloom/pdf/ref-frames.pdf
- https://www.google.com/search?q=parallel+transport+frame
- https://www.google.com/search?q=swept+surface